# Slim framework : upgrade from version 3 to version 4?

Tags: php, upgrade, slim

I've a [slimframework v3](https://github.com/dev-mansonthomas/RedCrossQuest) application that provide REST API for an Angular application.

I want to upgrade to v4, but there's quite a lot of changes and the upgrade page, while [it mention what is changing](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/upgrade.html), it's pretty dry on how to make those change and get a working application at the end.

For example, it says the new App() no longer takes the settings... ok... where does the settings go now ? Likely in the [Dependency Container](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/di.html) but this is changing too.
I fear that I will do a lot of code change and get a non working app and will spend ages on figuring out what's wrong.

So do you have any suggestion on how to proceed, step by step, to achieve a working upgrade from 3 to 4?

I've googled a bit, but I didn't find some walkthrough/tutorial on this subject.

Comment: I'm in similiar situation. My Slim app was coded before unit and functional tests. Now I want to develop the app tests trying to not make them independent of Slim version. After that, I will refactoring it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to perform the upgrade.
It's way too long to document it here, so I've made a blog post here :

https://blog.mansonthomas.com/2019/11/upgrade-slimframework-v3-to-v4-how-i.html

I'll improve the article (readability & content)